# Convolution with the poisson kernel (what is)

Tags: complex-analysis

[image: page1]

I am trying to work on the last part of the above problem. I am not sure what a 'convolution with the poisson kernel' is and consequently, a way to express $g(x+i\epsilon)- g(x-i\epsilon)$, or solve the problem. I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a bit of algebra $$g\left(x+i\varepsilon\right)-g\left(x-i\varepsilon\right)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-M}^{M}h\left(z\right)\left(\frac{1}{z-x-i\varepsilon}-\frac{1}{z-x+i\varepsilon}\right)dz$$ $$=\frac{\varepsilon}{\pi}\int_{-M}^{M}\frac{h\left(z\right)}{\left(z-x\right)^{2}+\varepsilon^{2}}dz=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}h\left(z\right)P_{\varepsilon}\left(x-z\right)dz=\left(h*P_{\varepsilon}\right)\left(x\right)$$ where $P_{\varepsilon}\left(x\right)$ is the Poisson kernel $P_{y}\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{y}{x^{2}+y^{2}}.$ Now it remanis to observe that $P_{\varepsilon}\left(y\right)$ is an approximate identity and so, since $h$ is continuous, $$\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0^{+}}\left(h*P_{\varepsilon}\right)\left(x\right)=h(x).$$

Comment: Thank you @MarcoCantarini. Is the expression in the first equality represent a convolution?

Comment: Why is $P_\epsilon(y)$ an identity.

Comment: I don't understand your question. From $g(x+i\varepsilon)-g(x-i\varepsilon)$ you can get the convolution of $h$ and $P_{\varepsilon}$, where $P_{\varepsilon}$ is the Poisson kernel. Now, since this function is an approximate identity (or an approximation of the identity) you can use a well-known result that, if $h$ is continuous, then the convolution of $h$ and an approximate identity converges to $h$. Take a look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Approximations_to_the_identity

Comment: Thank you @MarcoCantarini.